# PRISM + WPF - how to make region appear with animation?

Tags: wpf, animation, prism

I have a WPF application written using PRISM architecture (MVVM).

I have a 'Filters' **Button** at the top of the 'Main Window' region and a **ListView** with rows in it, looks like this :

[image: before]

I would like that when the 'Filters' button is pressed, a user-control will 'slide' (using animation) under the 'Filters' button and reveal itself, pushing the **ListView** and shrinking it ...

It should look like this when the user-control finishes to appear :

[image: after]

The control that appears will have a 'hide' button that will fire an animation the shrinks it back to the top till it's gone ...

How can I do this in PRISM ? Do I have to select a region for the user-control that appears ?

How do I tell the region to 'show' itself using animation ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `TransitioningContentControl` which is in [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/). If it is not what you need, then, I guess, you have to make your own `ContentControl`, where you can override methods, such as `OnContentChanged` or `OnApplyTemplate` and apply custom animation to the content. Once you have the control, setup a region on it, like with simple `ContentControl`

```
<toolkit:TransitioningContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="AnimatedControlRegion" />
```

register a view with this region

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("AnimatedControlRegion", () => container.Resolve<MyView>());
```

and navigate to it

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("AnimatedControlRegion", new Uri("MyView", UriKind.Relative));
```

or activate it

```
var view = container.Resolve<MyView>();
var region = regionManager.Regions["AnimatedControlRegion"];
region.Activate(view);
```